# Java extended class doesn't save variables, can it even do it?

Tags: java

So lets say I have 3 classes.

```
public class sup extends sup3{
    private int year, month;
    private sup2 supp = null;
    public sup(int year, int month){
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
        super.setYear(this.year);
        super.setMonth(this.month);
        createClass();
    }

    public void createClass(){
            sup2 supp = new sup2();
    }
}
```

Second class

```
public class sup2 extends sup3 {

    public sup2(){
        whatever();
    }

    public void whatever(){
        System.out.println(getYear() + " " + getMonth());
    }
}
```

And third class

```
public class sup3 {
    private int year, month;

    public void setYear(int year){

        this.year = year;
        System.out.println("Year: " + this.year);
    }
    public void setMonth(int month){
        this.month = month;
        System.out.println("Month: " + this.month);
    }
    public int getYear(){
        return this.year;
    }
    public int getMonth(){
        return this.month;
    }
}
```

And obviously main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sup suppp = new sup(2000, 15);
    }
}
```

So basically even though I set the sup3 variables trough the first class I can't see them in sup2 class even though I can access the sup3 class. I don't make and save the extended sup3 class anywhere so why can't I see the set variables everywhere?

It just prints out 0 0

Comment: sup2 extends its own instance of sup3

Comment: Note that an instance `sup` has _two different_ `year`s and _two different_ `month`s.  You duplicated the private variables.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Because they're the same names in constructors arguments and variables that the class has?

Comment: @CyprusN No, because you declared *fields* `year` and `month` again in `sub` when they were already declared in `sub3`. You are even double setting them in the constructor, thereby saying that you are aware that you have two different copies of the same fields.

Comment: @Andreas Gotcha, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simply, your class structure has created no relationship between `sup` and `sup2`.  Other than having a common parent, these two classes are completely separate things.

(Correction: `sup3` is the common parent class, not `sup` as a previous version of this answer suggested.)

Comment: How should I go about making a class that could save variables so all other classes could access them? Like in the example I give how to make that sup2 could access those set variables?

Comment: Why do you even think you want to do this?

Comment: So that if I have a lot of classes where some need maybe the variable year or month or both of them I don't have to pass them trough and could easily access them? But I guess that's not good coding

Comment: Yeah, this is the exact opposite of what is considered good software design these days.  May I suggest you do some reading on "encapsulation" and why we consider it to be important.